# Rails yield - content_for problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, yield, content-for

I have the following requirement.

Ex: There is a transaction table where it has columns say, transaction_name and amount. I want to loop through the transactions and display their details (transaction_name and amount) and finally I want to display the total amount (sum of all the amounts) in the head  (before the loop) section of my page. (Think about it as a summary display)

Example page structure would be like

**Sum of all the transactions - 200**

transaction    amount
trn1           100
trn2           50
trn3           50

And I tried to use yield and content_for tag but no luck.

my code is as follows (i'm calling inside my erb file.)

```
<%= yield :transaction_summary %> 

<table>
  <% total_amount = 0%>
  <%for transaction in @transactions%>
    <tr>
      <td><%= transaction.transaction_name %></td>
      <td><%= transaction.amount %></td>
      <% total_amount += transaction.amount %>
    </tr>
  <%end%>
  </table>

<% content_for :transaction_summary do %>
   <h1>
     Sum of all the transactions - <%= total_amount %>
   </h1>
<% end %>
```

And

I'm using with inside a view (**not inside a layout**)

I'm using rails 2.2.2

Please help me and let me know if there is a better way

thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

EDIT:

**Actually what I want to do is , Display some details before a particular loop where those details can be collected after the loop**

Ex: If i have an array of transaction objects, I want to show a count of pass and failed transactions before the transactions loop in my view

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the wrong idea about content_for and yield. :) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

```
   <h1>
     <%= @transactions.collect(&:amount).sum -%>
   </h1> 
   <table>
      <%for transaction in @transactions%>
        <tr>
          <td><%= transaction.transaction_name %></td>
          <td><%= transaction.amount %></td>
        </tr>
      <%end%>
    </table>
```

edit -

Regarding collecting data, I suggest you put them in helper methods:

```
#transactions_helper.rb
def transactions_total transactions
  @transactions_total ||= @transactions.collect(&:amount).sum
end

def passed_transactions transactions
  @passed_transactions ||= @transactions.collect{|transaction| transaction.passed == true}
end

def failed_transactions transactions
  @failed_transactions ||= transactions - passed_transactions(transactions)
end
```

Just noticed your comment to theTRON. The whole dry principle doesn't really apply to executing tiny logic such as looping through a array.

Comment: Hi mark,

Thanks for the replay. Even though your example works, i have some more functionalities such as getting the pass/ failed transaction count etc..

What I'm thinking is since I can get all my details after the loop, is there any rails way injecting those details to a html DIV which is above the loop

I have updated my post mentioning what i want to do 

And you are right, I think i miss understood the concept of content_for tag

thanks again and any help is welcome :D

Comment: Hi mark

Thank for the update 

"The whole dry principle doesn't really apply to executing tiny logic such as looping through a array " 

thats a good point. 

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 5):

In other cases where you really need to reuse content_for, the following may be useful.

In Rails 4, you can [pass `:flush => true`](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/07/flushing-content-blocks-with-rails-4/) as an option to content_for:

```
<% content_for :example, flush: true do %>
  <h1>Deletes previous content</h1>
<% end %>
```

In Rails 3.1.1 (approx) you can [delete the content from the view_flow when you yield](http://mikemayo.org/2012/rendering-a-collection-of-partials-with-content_for) by defining and using the following (eg in application_helper):

```
def yield_and_flush!(content_key)
  view_flow.content.delete(content_key)
end
```

Comment: that `:flush => true ` just made my day. thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for this in 2023! Both `view_flow.content.delete(:footer)` and passing `flush: true` to the content_for call are useful but are *not* equivalent. I needed to call content_for 4 times and then calling the appropriate yield before I called `view_flow.content.delete(:foo)` whereas if I used `flush: true` I would lose the previous 3 content_for calls' values.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a helper method which calculates the total separately, perhaps something along the lines of:

```
# app/helpers/transactions_helper.rb
def calculate_total(transactions)
 total = 0
 transactions.each {|transaction| total += transaction.amount}
 total
end
```

Then you can display it in your view wherever you like, with:

```
<%= calculate_total(@transactions) %>
```

Comment: Hi theTRON

Thanks for the reply. But I want a way of getting these details in a one loop. Since your proposed method includes two loops in the same result set namely

1 - helper method
2 - to display details in the view 

wonder if there is more DRY way of doing this

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3 you can yield after content_for; so your code will become:

```
<% content_for :transaction_table do %>
  <table>
    <% total_amount = 0%>
    <% for transaction in @transactions do %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= transaction.transaction_name %></td>
        <td><%= transaction.amount %></td>
        <% total_amount += transaction.amount %>
      </tr>
    <%end%>
  </table>

  <% content_for :transaction_summary do %>
     <h1>
       Sum of all the transactions - <%= total_amount %>
     </h1>
  <% end %>
<% end %> <!- End content_for :transaction_table -->


<%= yield :transaction_summary %> 
<%= yield :transaction_table %>
```

Note:

```
<% content_for :transaction_summary do %>
```

doesn't have to be inside of

```
<% content_for :transaction_table do %>
```

, but for some more complex cases it could.